# facebook iOS login button not asking permissions

Tags: ios, facebook

I have facebook login button which is initialised with next code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.facebookLoginButton = [FBSDKLoginButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.facebookLoginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
self.facebookLoginButton.delegate = self
```

The browser dialog appears, but requested permission is ONLY public profile. Any other are not nor requested. I get access token successfully. The only problem - is the permissions. Does anybody knows where can be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the access token just in case to see if these permissions are not already included? developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. This might happen if you played around with the Graph API Explorer and you already granted this permission.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I found the problem. facebookLoginButton was defined in XIB and fore some seasons it is not initialised in -viewDidLoad method. I've create local variable (facebookLoginButton) and added as subview with code. And after - it started to work correctly. Thank you!